# Поиск ответа (регулярное выражение)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

занимаюсь автоматизацией процесса сдачи теста, на данный момент программа работает но в ней не продуман процесс поиска ответа, примерная логика программы: получили список вопросов, нашли страничку с ответами, получили весь текст из страницы и парсим текст в поисках ответа, на данный момент я использую вот такую регулярку:

```
вопрос\\n(.*?)\\n
```

главный минус в ее статичности, если же между вопросом и ответом будет лишний перевод строки, слова типа **Ответ:** или же предложение типа **Выберите один ответ:** то все крах, возвращается то что находилось между вопросом и ответом, пока временно поставил парочку условии, знаю что это не совсем правильно так как таких условий может наплодиться штук десять а то и двадцать, подскажите как можно улучшить поиск? пишу на java использую библиотеку selenium + регулярные выражения.

Comment: А почему вообще вам приходится что-то парсить? В каком формате ваши входные данные, и почему вы не переведёте их в удобный формат?

Comment: @3Gern, присоединяюсь к мнению VladD'а вам стоит посмотреть в сторону [XML][1] или [JSON][2] для обоих форматов полным полно библиотек. Для JSON по идеи должны быть библиотеки способные сконфигурировать сразу нужную структуру в виде вложенных сетов, мапов, векторов и т.п. 


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML
  [2]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: @VladD готовых входных данных нету, суть программы искать ответ на какой та вопрос, проще это автоматизация процесса гугления в поисках ответа на какой та вопрос.
@ProkletyiPirat xml не подойдет, json не имею представления насчет него так что буду гуглит может подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

```
^([^:]*):(.*)
```

Comment: не подходит, если убрать двойные точки после вопроса все крах, пока сделал вот так: 
вопрос\\n(.*?)\\n(.*?)\\n
от условии не избавляет но по лучше работает чем прежняя.
не подскажите как парсить вот такую конструкцию
вопрос
ответ
\n
вопрос
ответ
\n
вопрос
ответ
нужно каждый вопрос ответ получить отдельно.